# Asp.Net Control inside div not showing up in browser

Tags: asp.net

I have a table made out of divs. Theere is a main div as the table, then divs acting as a table cell, and table row. Inside the cells I have a label and a textbox. All are Asp.Net controls(textbox,label). Everything seems to show up in the browser except for one particular column and I have no Idea why. The "maiden name" column won't show.

Code:

```
<div class="block">
           <div class="line">

                <div class="labelcell">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name: "  meta:resourcekey="lblPersonLastNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonLastName" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonLastNameResource1"/>
                </div>


                 <div class="labelcell">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonDateOfBirth" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth:" meta:resourcekey="lblPersonDateOfBirthResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonDateOfBirth" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonDateOfBirthResource1"/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regValDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPersonDateOfBirth" ErrorMessage="Date format must be YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY-MM-DD" ValidationExpression="(^[0-9]{4,4}(/|-)[0-1][0-9](/|-)[0-3][0-9]$)" ValidationGroup="AddPerson" meta:resourcekey="regValDateResource1">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="line">
               <div class="labelcell"> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name: " meta:resourcekey="lblPersonFirstNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">    
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonFirstNameResource1"/>
                </div>

                <div class="labelcell">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonAgeRange" runat="server" Text="Age Between:" meta:resourcekey="lblPersonAgeRangeResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonAgeRangeLow" runat="server" Width="30px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonAgeRangeLowResource1"/>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblPersonAgeRangeAnd" runat="server" Text="and" Height="25px" meta:resourcekey="lblPersonAgeRangeAndResource1"/>&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonAgeRangeHigh" runat="server" Width="30px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonAgeRangeHighResource1" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="line">
                <div class="labelcell">
                     <asp:Label ID="lblPersonMiddleName" runat="server" Text="Middle Name: " meta:resourcekey="lblPersonMiddleNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonMiddleName" runat="server" MaxLength="128" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonMiddleNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="labelcell">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonSex" runat="server" Text="Sex:" meta:resourcekey="lblPersonSexResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbPersonSexMale" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBinding="SexChange" OnCheckedChanged="SexChange" GroupName="PersonSex" Text="Male " meta:resourcekey="rdbPersonSexMaleResource1"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbPersonSexFemale" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBinding="SexChange"  OnCheckedChanged="SexChange" GroupName="PersonSex" Text="Female " meta:resourcekey="rdbPersonSexFemaleResource1" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="line">

            <div class="labelcell">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPersonStatus" runat="server" Text="Status:"  meta:resourcekey="lblPersonStatusResource1"/>
              </div>
              <div class="cell"> 
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPersonStatus" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="dsPersonStatus" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="StatusID" OnPreRender="ddlPersonStatus_PreRender" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="ddlPersonStatusResource1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
                 <div class="labelcell">
                     <asp:Label ID="lblPersonMaidenName" runat="server" Text="Maiden Name:" meta:resourcekey="lblPersonMaidenNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonMaidenName" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonMaidenNameResource1"/>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="line">
              <div class="labelcell">
                     <asp:Label ID="lblPersonThirdName" runat="server" Text="Third Name: " meta:resourcekey="lblPersonThirdNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonThirdName" runat="server" MaxLength="128" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonThirdNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="labelcell">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonFps" runat="server" Text="FPS: "  meta:resourcekey="lblPersonFpsResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonFps" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonFpsResource1"/>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="line">
                <div class="labelcell">
                     <asp:Label ID="lblPersonForthName" runat="server" Text="Fourth Name: " meta:resourcekey="lblPersonForthNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonForthName" runat="server" MaxLength="128" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonForthNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                 <div class="labelcell">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPersonEthnicity" runat="server" Text="Ethnicity:"  meta:resourcekey="lblPersonEthnicityResource1"/>
                 </div>
                <div class="cell">
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPersonEthnicity" Width="120px" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="dsPersonEthnicity" DataTextField="Ethnicity" DataValueField="EthnicityID" OnPreRender="ddlPersonEthnicity_PreRender" meta:resourcekey="ddlPersonEthnicityResource1">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div>

            </div> 
        </div>
```

This part seems to not won't to show up in the browser:

```
                <div class="labelcell">
                     <asp:Label ID="lblPersonMaidenName" runat="server" Text="Maiden Name:" meta:resourcekey="lblPersonMaidenNameResource1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonMaidenName" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Width="120px" meta:resourcekey="txtPersonMaidenNameResource1"/>
                </div>
```

How it shows up in HTML(the maiden name part):

```
<div class="labelcell"></div>

<div class="cell"></div>
```

Here is a "line" that does show up:

```
<div class="line">
              <div class="labelcell">
                     <span id="lblPersonThirdName">Third Name: </span>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <input name="txtPersonThirdName" type="text" maxlength="128" id="txtPersonThirdName" style="width:120px;">
                </div>
                <div class="labelcell">
                    <span id="lblPersonFps">FPS: </span>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"> 
                    <input name="txtPersonFps" type="text" maxlength="200" id="txtPersonFps" style="width:120px;">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The code here did not show any reason for that, maybe if you have it live.

Comment: Well, I just put the code there in case anyone asked to see it. This is seriously baffling me. All the other controls show up except for the the one line.

Comment: If you can post what is rendered in browser will give us some clue?

Comment: i will post the code in the main question

Comment: make sure that controls lblPersonMaidenName and txtPersonMaidenName are visible before page is rendered

Comment: @john on the back end (as in the debugger) - what is the value of the string at run-time that you are copying into the webcontrol's .Text property?  I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Server Controls that has Visible property set to false do not render to page html. Make sure that controls lblPersonMaidenName and txtPersonMaidenName are visible before page is rendered.